# How to use a procedure and user input to search for a date in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm getting an error message that tells me I'm entering an invalid number when I try to use a procedure I've made to search through and print records for a given year.
I also need to print records between two dates (e.g. Jan 2016 to Dec 2016) and I have no idea how to do that in the same procedure.

I've tried changing the parameter input type to VARCHAR and DATE, but they don't seem to work either

```
/*Procedure to search for sales by year*/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SalesReport(
    search_year IN NUMBER
)
IS
     -- Declare Cursor
    CURSOR year_search_cursor IS
        SELECT sp_invoice, sp_datesold, sp_saleprice, sp_addncost, sp_deposit, sp_total, sp_id, c_id, v_regno
        FROM sales_purchases
        WHERE sp_datesold LIKE '%' + search_year;
    -- Declare ROW record pointer
    sp_year_row year_search_cursor%ROWTYPE;
    rec_output  VARCHAR2(200); -- Output String 

BEGIN
    -- Column Headers
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invoice_No,'||'Date sold,'||'Sale Price $,'||'AddnCost,'||'Deposit,'||'Total,'||'SP_ID,'||'C_ID,'||'V_RegNo');
    -- Fetching data from cursor into variables
    FOR sp_year_row IN year_search_cursor LOOP
        rec_output:=
            sp_year_row.sp_invoice||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_datesold||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_saleprice||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_addncost||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_deposit||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_total||','||
            sp_year_row.sp_id||','||
            sp_year_row.c_id||','||
            sp_year_row.v_regno;        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_output);
    END LOOP;
END;
/


-- Get Input from User
ACCEPT search_year NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter search year: ';

-- Call the UPDATE_INV_SP Procedure and check stock amount status of item
EXECUTE SalesReport(&search_year);
```

Right now when I try to run the procedure using 'EXECUTE SalesReport(&search_year);' I just get the following error message

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN SalesReport(2015); END;
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at "19421463.SALESREPORT", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 1
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column is `date`, `LIKE` will not work. You need to get year out of it

```
`WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sp_datesold)  = search_year;`
```

or

```
`WHERE To_Char(sp_datesold, 'YYYY')  = search_year;`
```

To search range, you can use `BETWEEN`

```
`WHERE To_Char(sp_datesold, 'YYYY')  BETWEEN v_year1 and v_year2;`
```

These are not necessarily optimized but you get the idea

This is better. Note, I put strings there just for show. In reality, these should be dates come from parameters - important - no time part for `date1` and `date2`

```
Date1 date := to_date('01/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
Date2 date := to_date('12/31/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 1;
`WHERE sp_datesold >= date1 AND sp_datesold < date2;`
```

Comment: thanks for your help.
The good news is that its no longer throwing me an error.
The bad news is that when I execute SalesReport(&search_year) after entering 2015 into 'ACCEPT search_year NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter search year: ';' I get no printed lines.
I only get the output 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.' in the Script Output in Oracle SQL Developer.

I have tried using both 'WHERE EXTRACT/TO_CHAR' methods, and with neither I get any output after executing.

Comment: Did you `set serveroutput on`? If not, you won't see anything.